# Password field with numeric keyboard on android

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a password field with a numeric keyboard on a mobile application.

I use this line for the input :

```
<input type="password" id="password" data-i18n="[placeholder]app.login_verification"/>
```

When I switch the type to type="number" it shows the numeric keyboard but when I put something from keyboard it shows the numbers which I added.
So I need to hide them like "****".

Anyone ?

Comment: You could use [HTML text input allows only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allows-only-numeric-input) and the attribute `type="password"`.

Comment: Use this attribute in your edittext inside the xml file 
android:inputType="textPassword" or  android:inputType="numberPassword"

Comment: Use this for the number keyboard and non readable number password android:inputType="numberPassword"

Comment: Question shouldn't be marked as Duplicate as it is completely different framework. anyways. you should take input type as `number` and add style `-webkit-text-security: disc;` it will make test look like password characters.

Comment: I did not change the input type but just added this to the same line < ... style="-webkit-text-security: disc;" > like this and it did work.